# How can I write a dtrace script to dump the stack of a crashing process on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, crash-reports, dtrace

I have a process, running on Solaris 10, that is terminating due to a SIGSEGV. For various  uninteresting reasons it is not possible for me to get a backtrace by the usual means (gdb, backtrace call, corefile are all out). But I think dtrace might be useable.

If so, I'd like to write a dtrace script that will print the thread stacks of the process when the process is killed. I'm not very familiar with dtrace, but this seems like it must be pretty easy for someone who knows it. I'd like to be able to run this in such a way as to monitor a particular process. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else stumbles across this, I'm making some progress experimenting on OS X with the following script I've cobbled together:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

proc:::fault
/pid == $1/
{
        ustack();
}
```

I'll update this with a complete solution when I have one.

Comment: adb (mdb really) will analyze the stack of a core dump.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't have corefiles.

Comment: OK, this *almost* works, however it only sometimes symbolizes the stack trace, which is necessary. It seems that the process termination due to the segfault is racing with ustack, as mentioned here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-user/index.html. However, I haven't been able to make any suggested workarounds stick. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, FYI, I'm doing my testing on OS X, but the customer system where I need to ultimately run this is Solaris 10.

Comment: Your tags has one for Solaris: In Solaris you force a core dump on a live process with gcore,  this creates a core file.  Then use mdb. Dtrace is a great tool, if you plan on using it extensively, great, put lots of time in developing something so you can learn. It does have a steep learning curve: my DTRACE (Gregg & Mauro) book has 1100+ pages.  I have not learned half of it in 2 years of off/on use.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Not an option I'm afraid. Customer will not provide corefiles, and I do not have access to their system. I am trying to develop a dtrace script for them to run. So again, corefiles are not an option, nor is a debugger.

Comment: @jimmcnamara haha thanks. Yeah not ideal debugging circumstances by any means, but such is life.

Comment: Dtrace will give the current stack but not necessarily the stack when the process crashes. If they are willing to run DTrace on the process why not run it under mdb to get the stack?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of Solaris engineers wrote a script for using Dtrace to capture crash data and published an article on using it, which can now be found at [Oracle Technology Network: Enabling User-Controlled Collection of Application Crash Data With DTrace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/app-crash-142906.html).

One of the authors also published a number of updates to his blog, which can still be read at https://blogs.oracle.com/gregns/, but since he passed away in 2007, there haven't been any further updates.